# Powershell read csv and get data that equals username

Tags: csv, powershell, powershell-3.0, signature

I'm working on a powershell script that generates Outlook html signatures.
It now works but you need to fill in all the template words manually (name email telephone etc)

What i want is that when you run the powershell script it checks for the logged in user and gets the info for that user from the CSV file and fills it in the html template.

What is the best approch to do this?

What i got now is:

```
$html_template = @"
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
  etc etc etc
"@

# Simulate how ever you are querying for data.
$desktop_path = "$env:userprofile\Desktop\"
$filename = [Environment]::UserName

# Does nothing only import
$content = Import-CSV -Path D:\export.csv

# Input fields
$name= Read-Host -Prompt 'Input name (eg. Tim Tom)'
$title= Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the job title (eg. Office Manager)'
$phone= Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the last 3 telephone numbers (eg. 111)'
$email= Read-Host -Prompt 'Input email adress (eg. name@domain.nl)'

# Check if map Handtekeningen exist else force create it.
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path C:\Users\$filename\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Handtekeningen | Out-Null

# Create html file
$html_template -f $name,$title,$phone,$email,$filename | Out-File -Force $desktop_path\$filename.html

# Set file to Readonly (problem is it cannot be overwriten)
Set-ItemProperty $desktop_path\$filename.html -name IsReadOnly -value $true

# Write
Write-Host "Saving signature."
Write-Host "Closing in 5 seconds."

# Sleep for 5 seconds
Start-Sleep -s 5
```

csv:

```
username;Full Name;Job Title;Telephone;Email
```

Comment: This makes little sense in parts. Your CSV is empty, you import a CSV, but query the user for values directly afterwards. But in general the approach you use seems fine, i.e. define a template with placeholders (in this case a .NET format string), get the data you need to insert, fill out the template and write it somewhere. I've used similar code a lot of times. So where exactly are you having problems? Especially the CSV part is unclear to me – do you want to create a single signature? Or a lot of them?

Comment: I know what i want but dont know how to do it, i never worked with csv files, i just need to read 1 row that matches the username. I just need a little first step

Comment: I want to create 1 for the user that runs it, and all the users are in the csv file with name email telephone etc.

Comment: So you're essentially looking for `$currentUser = $content | where username -eq $Env:username`?

Comment: Yes so i have a csv with all the employees every employee has 1 row with username (to filter so the script knows what data he needs when the script is run) and then the data for the signature, real name, job title, telephone number, email adress.
The script needs to see who started the script (so the username), then get the data and set the variables for the html template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (after your comments) I understood you correctly, you merely need to figure out what row to use from the CSV file. In that case you can read the user name from the environment variable `USERNAME` and simply filter appropriately:

```
$content = Import-CSV -Path D:\export.csv

$user = $content | where username -eq $Env:USERNAME

if (!$user -or $user.Count -gt 1) {
  throw 'No user, or multiple users found'
}

# Input fields
$name= $user.'Full Name'
$title= $user.'Job Title'
$phone= $user.Telephone
$email= $user.'Email'
```

Comment: Man you are my HERO!!! Works just how i wanted it to work! Thanks have a nice weekend :)